# setTimeout() and dropping markers on google map

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why setTimeout is not working as I expected.

I want to drop each marker on a different time, not all at the same time.

Paste and run this code into http://jsfiddle.net, then remove comments in order to see the funny behavior:

```
        //setTimeout(function() {
            addMarker(m);
        //}, i * 500);
```

.

```
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var berlin = new google.maps.LatLng(52.520816, 13.410186);
  var neighborhoods = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.511467, 13.447179),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.549061, 13.422975),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.497622, 13.396110),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.517683, 13.394393)
  ];
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: berlin
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
  }

  function drop() {
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
        var m = neighborhoods[i];
        //setTimeout(function() {
            addMarker(m);
        //}, i * 500);
    }
  }
  function addMarker(m) {
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: m,
      map: map,
      draggable: false,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
  }
</script>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;">map div</div>
<button id="drop" onclick="drop()">Drop Markers</button>
</body>
```

Comment: why dont you paste the code in the jsfiddle and post the link to it ?

Comment: jsfiddle is migrating servers and currently anyone can not save code on it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the value of 'm' has changed long before the timeOut event triggers.

You should wrap this code in a closure so as to capture the value of m.

Something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
    var m = neighborhoods[i];

    (function(n){
      setTimeout(function() {
        addMarker(n);
     }, i * 500);
   }(m));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your iteration over the neighborhoods and the locale variable `var m = neighborhoods[i]`. The value of `m`, which is used in `addMarker(m)` is replaced by the very last element in `neighborhoods`, which will result in all markers drop on the same spot.

Use the following code instead ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4auTQ/)). It iterates over a global counter, which you could replace by a static variable and sets an interval instead of a timeout:

```
  var droppedCount = 0;
  var droppedInterval = null;

  function drop() {
    if(droppedCount === neighborhoods.length){
        clearInterval(droppedInterval);
        return;
    }
    else if(droppedInterval === null)
        droppedInterval = setInterval(drop,500);

    var m = neighborhoods[droppedCount++];
    addMarker(m);
  }
```

Comment: yes, I understand that, the value is constantly (4), but why? how can i solve it?

Comment: @lito: I've updated my answer. Use a global or static (`drop.droppedCount`) counter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function in the setTimeout closes over the *variable* m, not the current value of it at time of creation. The solution should be:

```js
// ...
var m = neighborhoods[i];
(function (myMarker) {
setTimeout(function() {
    addMarker(myMarker );
}, i * 500);
}(m));
// ...
```